# $_POST within heredoc php

Tags: php, heredoc

I need to display the "name" value after submitting. My code doesn't work. 
I know, that the easiest way is just to use "**echo $_POST["name"]**", but the task is to understand how "heredoc" works. I just started to learn PHP. Is there a mistake here?

*test.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="test.php" method="post">

    Name: <input type="text" name="name">

    <input type="submit">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

*test.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

    $y = <<<HERE
        $_POST["name"]
HERE;

    echo $y;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean it does't work?  Are you getting an error message? If you're getting a blank screen, make sure you either put some more content on your page to ensure you're page is actually rendering and not dying due to some parsing error.

Comment: [**Error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) which you're not using `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)`

Comment: actually, I don't get an error message, just a blank screen. how can I set php to get error messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use curly braces.

```
$y = <<<HERE
    {$_POST["name"]}
HERE;
```

It's the same as you would if you were just creating a string

```
$y = "Name = {$_POST['name']}";
```

Read more about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php.  Look for the section called Complex (curly) syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Yo cannot directly use a reference to an array within a heredoc statement. You have to enclose it between curly braces

```
$y = <<<HERE
   {$_POST["name"]}
HERE;
```

or

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$y = <<<HERE
   $name
HERE;
```

Comment: the 2nd option work well, but I wanted to know hot to put correctly $_POST into heredoc